# Custom Marker frame size in Google Maps

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios8, xcode6, google-maps-sdk-ios

How to change the size of custom marker in iOS using google maps? I am using goole maps SDK for iOS. It sets the marker size according to image. But my image is higher resolution. So how I can set the frame

```
marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
marker.position = location;
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
if(image)
{
    marker.icon = image;
}

marker.map = _mapView;`
```

Comment: This library should be helpful: https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit

Comment: And if you do not wish to use the library you can make changes in the source code. Since it is custom marker image you would have to handle it as you would handle any image elem. Here's another link that'd be helpful: http://code.developwithus.com/iphone/resize-image-in-iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a custom icon for the markers, you have to implement it as an [UIImage object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker#change_the_default_marker_icon).

Pay attention to this line in the documentation:

> Custom icons are always set as a UIImage object.

Once you set it up, you can adjust the size with either of the methods from the comment.

Hope this helped.